# Get specific column from Data Table C#

Tags: c#, excel, list, datatable

I'm having a Data Table who gets values from some excel file. I use button as File dialog, find file somewhere in file system and then I parse needed values there. 
Later in application I'm gonna need just one column from that Data Table. It is column named `max t` on picture attached. 
Below is the code I'm using to get values from file:

```
  string pathConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
  OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(pathConnection);
  OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [DAYTIME CONFORT INDEX$]", connection);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
  myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

[image]

As you can see on picture I have few columns but only need some of them. For example I need to get values from column `max t` into some list of doubles.
I've tried few things but non of them didn't worked. Since I'm a beginner with this can someone help me with easiest way to do this.
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List columns you need in query. E.g. getting only columns `M` and `max t`:

```
"Select [M],[max t] from [DAYTIME CONFORT INDEX$]"
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick respond. Didn't know I can do that. Will try it right away :)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an array values from the max t Column from your dataTable

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "max t");
DataRow[] myRows = distinctValues.Select();
```

Comment: Thanks for response I will try both answers I've got and I'll see which one works better for me :D